# How to copy o/p of any xslt file to another xslt file?

Tags: xslt

I am using an xslt to generate some xml. Is there any way to copy the o/p from 1 xslt and use that in main calling xslt?

here is scenario:
1. There are 2 xslt's `ABC.xslt` and `XYZ.xslt`
2. Main Xslt is lets say `ABC.xslt` which will make a call to `XYZ.xslt` and copy its o/p to `ABC.xslt` using `<xsl:copy-of select=""/>`?

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Really not clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer...
step 1:

```
<xsl:import href="name of xslt to be included" />
```

Step 2: use

```
<xsl:apply-imports/>
```

done :-) :-)